# Git commit vsidx file access denied in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, git-commit

I've recently updated Visual Studio to 17.8 and since then I can no longer do a Git commit.

The error it displays at the top of the Git panel is:
Git failed with a fatal error
error: open ("......\FileContentIndex...vsidx"):Access Denied

I'm running in Administrator mode, and I've removed the read only access from the repo folders.
I've tried deleting the FileContentIndex but VS just recreates it.
Tried Git add . but still cannot access index file.
Tried it reset with no success.

Somehow this index file is preventing me from committing my changes.
There's no options to disabled indexing. I'm running Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.8.2 (Not preview)

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Git-failed-with-a-fatal-error/10526402?space=41&sort=newest

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to commit the .vs folder.

You should be git ignoring it.

Comment: Thanks Matt Evans. You're absolutely right. I went Git > Settings > Source Control > Git Repository Settings...  Then added the .gitignore file which by default included the .vs folder. This worked.